# Start Tomcat through cronjob

Tags: tomcat, cron

To make sure that Tomcat is running all the time, I wrote the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

status="$(curl -s http://www.domain.com/check)"

if [ "$status" != "OK" ]
then
    /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/startup.sh
    /usr/sbin/sendmail me@domain.com < email.txt
fi
```

and added it to the crontab via

`*/1 * * * * /opt/scripts/check.sh`

Now if I shut down the server manually, then I receive an email every minute but for some reason the script won't start Tomcat. However, if I execute `check.sh` manually, I receive an email and Tomcat starts running again.

Any ideas as to why adding the script to the crontab does not start Tomcat?

Comment: Which crontab exactly? Did you forget to specify a user?

Comment: I used `crontab -e`. By specifying a user, do you mean putting the username in between `*`  and `/opt...`?

Comment: If you used `crontab -e` then it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is environment variables, i.e. an interactive shell has a lot (including a rather complete $PATH), whereas for programs run from cron they are typically heavily limited (including an abbreviated path).

Answer (score 1):

@Craig Miskell: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This is how I solved the problem:

First, I added the following lines of code to `/etc/crontab`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/root
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_25
```

Second, I updated the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_25
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin

status="$(curl -s http://www.domain.com/check)"

if [ "$status" != "OK" ]
then
    /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/startup.sh
    /usr/sbin/sendmail me@domain.com < email.txt
fi
```

The entry in `crontab -e` I didn't touch at all.

Thanks again, I hope this helps!